# UICollectionView's prefetchItemsAt not being called

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to implement data prefetching for my `UICollectionView` using the `UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching` protocol; however, the respective method is not being called.
The collection view has a [custom layout](https://github.com/klundberg/KRLCollectionViewGridLayout). I have also tried with the regular flow layout, same results.
Upon data reload, I execute the following code to make the collection view have the size of its content to prevent scrolling within that collection view but in a scroll view outside the collection view:

```
func reloadData() {
    viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    collectionView.reloadData()
    collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
    viewDidLayoutSubviews()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
    collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Maybe that has something to do with it?

#### What I have done:

- my `UIViewController` **does** inherit from `UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching`
- `collectionView.prefetchDataSource = self` (also tried using storyboard)
- `collectionView.isPrefetchingEnabled = true` (also tried using storyboard)
- I have implemented `collectionView(_:prefetchItemsAt:)`

#### Issue:

The `prefetchItemsAt` method is not being called. I determined that by placing a `print` statement in the method & setting up a breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I execute the following code to make the collection view have the size of its content to prevent scrolling within that collection view but in a scroll view outside the collection view:

This sounds very broken.

Why are you doing this?

Prefetching on the collection view (from the docs) is triggered when the user scrolls the collection view. By making the collection view frame the same as the content size you are essentially disabling the scrolling of the collection view itself.

> The collection view calls this method as the user scrolls

If you are forcing the collection view frame to be the same as the content size then you are entirely breaking `UICollectionView`.

The reason the prefetch isn't called is because every cell has been loaded already. Nothing is in prefetch any more. Because your collection view is displaying every cell at the same time.

If you want to scroll a collection view... let the collection view handle it. You shouldn't need to place the collection view inside another scroll view.

Comment: *This sounds very broken* - The point is that I have multiple different collection views in that view controller and I want to scroll through the whole view controller. Hence, I have a scroll view with multiple different views inside, one of which is this collection view.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the second part. I have realized that `willDisplay:` is being called for all cells at view did load. After disabling the resizing of the collection view that isn't the case anymore. Same for the prefetching. Any suggestions on how I can have both the resizing of the collection view *and* the prefetching?

Comment: In that case you should really be using one collection view with different sections or something. Currently your setup will like cause the app to crash if you have a lot of items in your collection. Every single item is being loaded and placed into a cell as soon as your view is created. Regardless of if it is on screen or not. If you have 10,000 images in your data then that is 10,000 image view with 10,000 bits of memory being taken up, etc...

Comment: Right, I get the point. In my case that won't be an issue because there will never be that much data to load. Any idea besides the sections?

Comment: **Any suggestions on how I can have both the resizing of the collection view and the prefetching?** Don't resize the collection view. The collection view frame should not be any bigger than the screen.

Comment: If you want to prefetch... don't break the collection view. :D That's really all there is to it. Or maybe look again at how you are approaching the problem from a design perspective etc...

Comment: Update: I've come up with a solution: I use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` to determine how close to the bottom the user is scrolling, and then I fetch the next items, if not fetching already. That works well for me. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: hi @LinusGeffarth do u mind sharing your solution. I'm also looking for a way to prefetch working with self-sizing collectionview. Seem only work with fix size cell

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh I've posted my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

Like requested in the comments, I'll share my implementation for this issue here:

I created the tracker `prefetchState` which determines whether I'm prefetching at the moment, or not:

```
enum PrefetchState {
    case fetching
    case idle
}
var prefetchState: PrefetchState = .idle
```

Then, I hooked up the scroll view's delegate (the scroll view my collection view is in) to my view controller and implemented the `scrollViewDidScroll` method:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    guard scrollView == self.scrollView else { return }

    let prefetchThreshold: CGFloat = 100 // prefetching will start 100pts above the bottom of the scroll view
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y > scrollView.contentSize.height-screenBounds.height-prefetchThreshold {
        if prefetchState == .idle {
            prefetchItems()
        }
    }
}
```

In there, you can see that I check whether we're already prefetching. If not, I call `prefetchItems()`, as implemented here:

```
func prefetchItems() {
    guard prefetchState == .idle else { return }
    prefetchState = .fetching
    someDownloadFuncWithCompletionBlock { (newItems) in
        self.dataSource += newItems
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        self.prefetchState = .idle
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a detail explanation. one question is how many items should we request in the function someDownloadFuncWithCompletionBlock? any change needed if user change scrolling direction?

Comment: Well that's on you. You can just use a fixed number of items. Depending on how big your cells are. For me, I had a max. of 6 cells on screen at once. So I prefetched 12 because that gives me two more pages, basically without fetching too many which would cause longer loading times and more data consumption.

Comment: what if the items are coming from an API with pagination and prefetch happen almost same time when collectionview reaches bottom which trigger loadmore function. In that case our prefetch might exceed exsting items

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by that. In my case, that's actually what's happening. I just keep track of the page number and increment it every time the `prefetchItems()` function is called.

Comment: Thanks at least there is a solution until Apple decides to support auto sizing cell prefetching